# If $X$ follows Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$ then what is the distribution of $X-2$?

Tags: probability-distributions

If X is Poisson then I know the m.g.f is exp(λ[$e^t$−1]). And i need to find out the m.g.f of X-2. I am not able to reach the answer given.
I am thinking X-2 is also Poisson with mean λ-2 but I am not sure whether I am right.
Please help me. Thankyou.

I have proceeded in this way:
Since X~Poisson(λ)
So m.g.f is given by $M_x$(t)=$e^λ$[$e^t$−1]

Now, Y=X-2~Poisson(λ-2)
So m.g.f is given by $M_y$(t)=exp(λ-2)[$e^t$-1]
                             =exp(λ$e^t$-2$e^t$-λ+2)

But the correct answer given in my book is $M_y$(t)=exp(λ$e^t$-2t-λ)

Comment: Since you didn't use Latex, it is not clear what you meant. Did you mean $X^2$ and $\lambda^2$?

Comment: Use the definition of MGF, that's all.

Comment: No, its just X-2 and λ-2 not squared.

Comment: I did use the definition but I am not able to solve it.

Comment: Show your work in the main post by editing it. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial for typesetting math here.

Comment: I have edited my post now.

Comment: By definition, I mean start from $M_Y(t)=E(e^{tY})=E(e^{t(X-2)})$. How does that relate to $M_X(t)=E(e^{tX})$? Since support of $X$ is $\{0,1,\ldots\}$, it is clear that $X-2$ cannot be Poisson.

Comment: Yes. I understood now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I proceeded in the following way.

We know that $M_{a+bx}$$(t)$= $E$$[e^{(a+bx)t}]$   =  $e^{at}$$E$$[e^{btx}]$ = $e^{at}$ $M_x(bt)$.

Now X~P($\lambda$)

This implies $M_x(t)$=$e^{\lambda(e^t -1)}$

Y=X-2 $\Rightarrow$ X=Y+2
$$\Rightarrow M_X(t)=M_{Y+2}(t) = E(e^{(y+2)t})$$
$$=e^{2t}E(e^{yt})$$
$$e^{2t} M_Y(t)$$

$$\Rightarrow e^{\lambda(e^t-1)}=e^{2t} M_Y(t)$$
$$\Rightarrow M_Y(t)=\frac{e^{(\lambda e^t - \lambda)}}{e^{2t}}$$
$$=e^{\lambda e^t - 2t - \lambda}$$